# How do I change the text size / font in python

Tags: python, text, fonts, size

I've recently been trying to make a basic game, but I cant change the font size of individual words. I managed to do it in tkinter but it made a pop up window and was very clunky. Was wondering if there was a cleaner, easier way to do this.

Comment: explanation is missing, also post your code

Comment: You'll need to use some GUI toolkit. There are lots to choose from. Just choose one, follow a tutorial, and have a go. Come back if you have more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing your first game in Python, tkinter probably isn't the best place to start. Unless there's a particular reason to use that, Pygame Zero is designed to make it easy to get started making games and its text drawing lets you set the size easily:
https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ptext.html